# #define a tuple in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, avr

I want to be able to define a tuple which represents the arguments needed by other macros.

I think the best way to show what I want is to show an example:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

#define LED_PORT PORTB
#define LED_DDR  DDRB
#define LED_PIN  PB7
#define LED      LED_PORT, LED_DDR, LED_PIN

#define OUTPUT(port, ddr, pin) ddr |= 1 << pin

void main(void) {
    OUTPUT(LED);
}
```

I want `OUTPUT(LED)` to be then expanded into:

```
LED_DDR |= 1 << LED_PIN
```

The problem that I get is to do with the order of expansion, and results in the following error:

> macro "OUTPUT" requires 3 arguments, but only 1 given

This is for use with an AVR project with custom built hardware where I have defined `LED` and other components with a respective `LED_PORT` `LED_DDR` and `LED_PIN`.

I then want to define more macros that can take this LED and use the appropriate arguments to map to the most succinct way possible.

Is this possible with the standard C-preprocessor?

Comment: Show the definition of `LET_PIN` and `LET_PORT` and `LET_DDR` and `OUTPUT`. So *edit your question* to improve it.

Comment: I would tag this question with [tag:c-preprocessor].

Comment: Can we assume that `PORTB`, `DDRB`,  `PB7` are literal integer constants ?

Comment: @Michas that tag didn't come up. Will try again.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `PB7` is an integer constant, `PORTB` and `DDRB` are of the form `(*(volatile uint8_t*) (some_address))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a level of indirection to the macro to achieve this:

```
#define OUTPUT_I(port, ddr, pin) ddr |= 1 << pin
#define OUTPUT(spec) OUTPUT_I(spec)
```

During rescanning, `spec` is expanded before `OUTPUT_I`, so the `OUTPUT_I` macro sees three parameters.

Comment: I have the impression this won't compile. `OUTPUT_I` expects three parameter.

Comment: @alk And it gets three parameters, because the function argument is expanded before the function macro during rescanning (as I mentioned in the answer).

Comment: Ahok, so you assume `LED` is being passed as per the OP? If so, adding a "How to use" might be a good idea.

Comment: Exactly. I've used a similar trick before: `#define FOO (1, 2)`, `#define BAR_I(x, y) ...`, `#define BAR(spec) BAR_I spec`; that works for the same reasons. The rules of the preprocessor are arcane, but adding a level of indirection does solve many problems you can have with it. Always worth a try.

Comment: Seems to do the trick. Now trying with my `WRITE` function that will take a fourth argument as well as the `spec`. Should work the same, just require passing through the second arg as the fourth.

Comment: In the  usage of the suffix `_I` does the `I` stand for anything? "Implementation"?

Comment: I think of it as "indirect." Any name will do, though, so if you find it confusing, choose something else. I don't think there's an established convention for this sort of thing.